# Downloading data from URL in R

Tags: r, url

I would like to download data from the following url 'https://ghoapi.azureedge.net/api/HWF_0006'.

I have tried this:

```
library(RCurl)
content <- getURL ('https://ghoapi.azureedge.net/api/HWF_0006')
```

And this is the error message that i got:

```
> content <- getURL ('https://ghoapi.azureedge.net/api/HWF_0006')
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to ghoapi.azureedge.net port 443: Timed out
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you very much,

N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it looks like you're trying to read a JSON file. You can easily do that with `jsonlite` package:

```r
library(jsonlite)

df <- fromJSON('https://ghoapi.azureedge.net/api/HWF_0006')
```

And parse it/unnest it as you please.

Comment: > df <- fromJSON('https://ghoapi.azureedge.net/api/HWF_0006')
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  Failed to connect to ghoapi.azureedge.net port 443: Timed out

Comment: Same here.. "failed to connect". I guess it has nothing to do with the code?

Comment: That's interesting, no problem for me on `jsonlite` V1.6 and `curl` V4.3

Comment: Ok, so it works when doing this:library(jsonlite)
con <- url("https://ghoapi.azureedge.net/api/HWF_0006", "rb")
df <- fromJSON(con)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `rvest`

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://ghoapi.azureedge.net/api/HWF_0006'

data_list <- read_html(url) %>% html_text() %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()
```

`data_list[[2]]` returns a dataframe and maybe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: > url <- 'https://ghoapi.azureedge.net/api/HWF_0006'
> 
> data_list <- read_html(url) %>% html_text() %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  Failed to connect to ghoapi.azureedge.net port 443: Timed out

Comment: Works fine for me actually. Are you under a firewall connection?